# Is it a total or an explicite time derivative in the Schrödinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, time, schroedinger-equation

I am always dubious when I need write Schrödinger equation: do I write $\partial / \partial t$ or $d/dt$ ?

I suppose it depends on the space in which it is considered. How?

Answer (score 11):

The most general Schrödinger equation has total derivatives
$$ i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle = \hat H |\psi\rangle $$
because the state vector $|\psi\rangle$ only depends on one variable, $t$. It's a complicated object that knows about the probability of anything in the given state, but this is hidden "inside" the state vector.

However, if you rewrite the state vector in a given representation, e.g. as $\psi(t,x,y,z,X,Y,Z)$ for the wave function of two particles, then the dependence on $x,y,z,X,Y,Z$, the coordinates of two particles, is put on equal footing with the $t$-dependence, and therefore the $t$-derivatives have to be written as partial ones, $\partial/\partial t$, to emphasize that $x,y,z,X,Y,Z$ are kept fixed during the differentiation.
$$ i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(t,x,y,z,X,Y,Z) = \hat H \psi(t,x,y,z,X,Y,Z) $$
where the Hamiltonian contains things like the kinetic energy of the first particle
$$ \hat H = \dots -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left(
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} +
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} +
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} 
\right)+\dots $$
and similarly the kinetic energy of the second particle
$$ \hat H = \dots -\frac{\hbar^2}{2M} \left(
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial X^2} +
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial Y^2} +
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial Z^2} 
\right)+\dots $$
Note that there are partial derivatives everywhere because $\psi$ is now not a "general state vector" whose information is compactified; it is a complex-valued function of many variables.

Comment: Well, that is what I would have said. But both in my course and in Oxford quantum course $\partial$ is used instead of $d$ even in "the most general Schrödinger equation" ... So I am still not convinced.